# HTTP Response with Multiple Layout Images in one PNG Image

Tags: javascript, http, web, png

I was playing around inspecting amazon.com http responses and I noticed this [HERE](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/sprites/nav-sprite-global-1x-hm-dsk-reorg._CB405937547_.png) as you can see the images used in the page layout are contained in one PNG image,

[image: screenshot from chrome devtools]

- Is this a known approach ?
- As I imagine, The JavaScript on the page will place each part of the image in the right place accoarding to a specific X&Y positions in that image, Is this really what's happening ?
- Why are they doing this instead of requesting each image ? Is a new request more expensive than in-browser image processing ? (if my above assumption is correct)
- Suggestions for further reading on this thing is much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, typically, "requests for further reading" are not appropriate questions for SO. Those questions are usually closed, but since you had other questions as well I answered instead of voting close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a known approach ?

Yes. These are called CSS sprites. They reduce the number of image requests made by only requesting a single image and then only displaying the parts of the image that are needed.

> As I imagine, The JavaScript on the page will place each part of the image in the right place accoarding to a specific X&Y positions in that image, Is this really what's happening ?

Yes. Correct. Well, maybe. Could be Javascript, but a CSS-only solution is more common.

> Why are they doing this instead of requesting each image ? Is a new request more expensive than in-browser image processing ? (if my above assumption is correct)

Yes. Correct. Less requests means faster page loads, typically.

> Suggestions for further reading on this thing is much appreciated

Here's a tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Here's the example from that tutorial:

```css
.flags-canada, .flags-mexico, .flags-usa {
  background-image: url('https://i0.wp.com/css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flags-canada {
  height: 128px;
  background-position: -5px -5px;
}

.flags-usa {
  height: 135px;
  background-position: -5px -143px;
}

.flags-mexico {
  height: 147px;
  background-position: -5px -288px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Full image</h3>
<img src='https://i0.wp.com/css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/sprite.png'>

<h3>Canada</h3>
<div class='flags-canada'></div>

<h3>USA</h3>
<div class='flags-usa'></div>

<h3>Mexico</h3>
<div class='flags-mexico'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer